# R: How to delete rows that differ from another row in just one (two, three) column?

Tags: r

I have a data frame similar to the following example. Sometimes, rows contain the same information about an object as in another row except for one (or several) columns, which contain "NA". I only want rows with as much information as possible, so I want to delete all rows that contain an "NA" but otherwise have the same information as another row. The "NA" may be in column C or D or in both (never in A or B). If there is no "more accurate" row, the row containing "NA" has to remain.

I've tried this using a for loop (see example) and it works, rows 1 and 6 will be deleted. However, I would have to adjust it to also check for column C and in my real data I have some more columns and thus some more possible combinations, which makes this solution impractical and can lead to errors.

Is there any other way to easily solve this?
Thanks!

```
df <- rbind(data.frame(A = "obj1", B = "1", C = "2", D = "NA"), 
            data.frame(A = "obj1", B = "1", C = "2", D = "3"),
            data.frame(A = "obj2", B = "1", C = "NA", D = "3"),
            data.frame(A = "obj2", B = "1", C = "2", D = "3"),
            data.frame(A = "obj2", B = "3", C = "2", D = "3"),
            data.frame(A = "obj2", B = "3", C = "2", D = "NA"),
            data.frame(A = "obj3", B = "2", C = "4", D = "6"),
            data.frame(A = "obj4", B = "2", C = "NA", D = "NA"))

toBeDeleted <- c(55)

for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
  thisRow <- df[i,]

  if (thisRow$D == "NA"){
    for (j in i:nrow(subset(df, A == thisRow$A))){
      anotherRow <- df[j,]
      if (anotherRow$A == thisRow$A & anotherRow$B == thisRow$B 
          & anotherRow$C == thisRow$C & anotherRow$D != thisRow$D){
        toBeDeleted <- c(toBeDeleted,i)
      }
    }
  }
}

df2 <- df[-toBeDeleted,]
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use a combination of `duplicated(df[1:2])` and `duplicated(df[1:2], fromLast = TRUE)` together with `rowSums(is.na(df)) > 0` to exclude all the rows which have `NA` and are duplicates:

```
df <- rbind(data.frame(A = "obj1", B = "1", C = "2", D = NA), 
            data.frame(A = "obj1", B = "1", C = "2", D = "3"),
            data.frame(A = "obj2", B = "1", C = NA, D = "3"),
            data.frame(A = "obj2", B = "1", C = "2", D = "3"),
            data.frame(A = "obj2", B = "3", C = "2", D = "3"),
            data.frame(A = "obj2", B = "3", C = "2", D = NA),
            data.frame(A = "obj3", B = "2", C = "4", D = "6"),
            data.frame(A = "obj4", B = "2", C = NA, D = NA))

df[!((duplicated(df[1:2]) | duplicated(df[1:2], fromLast = TRUE)) & rowSums(is.na(df)) > 0),]

     A B    C    D
2 obj1 1    2    3
4 obj2 1    2    3
5 obj2 3    2    3
7 obj3 2    4    6
8 obj4 2 <NA> <NA>
```

It is a simple subset, therefore no loop is needed and it is very fast even with huge data. It works like this:

We call the data `df[]` and exclude with `!()` all rows that have duplicates on the first two columns `df[1:2]` and that have at least one `NA` value `rowSums(is.na(df)) > 0`. For this to work, you need real `NA` in your data, not the `character` `"NA"` which were in your example data above. If you only have `"NA"`, use `rowSums(df == "NA") > 0` instead.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't understand yet, what it does and will have to see how I can adapt it to my actual data frame.

Comment: I'll add a more thorough explanation.